# angularjs : clearing form after submit shows error message?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-validation

Hi I have form where I am using many fields. After submitting and if everythign goes fine I am clearing or setting form to default state but I am still getting error message.

```
<div>
        <span>Type:</span>
        <select class="chosen" name="type" required="" chosen="exp.transactionType" ng-model="exp.selectedTransactionType"
            ng-options="tt.value for tt in exp.transactionType">
        </select>
        <div class="error-msg" ng-show="form.$submitted || form.type.$touched">
            <span class="error-msg" ng-show="form.type.$error.required">Select transaction type.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set pristine of your form.
Lets say your form name is "myForm", so just after clearing your form, you can do the following

```
$scope.myForm.$setPristine();
```